# The connection was reset issue with Codeigniter in localhost (Only for 1 controller)

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp

I am experiencing an issue with Codeigniter in WAMP server. I am using 2 controllers for my project.
One is working fine. But when I try to access the 2nd controller methods,
**"This site can’t be reached The connection was reset."** window appearing.
There was no issue before. The problem starts to seen today.
Hope you can give any suggestions.

Comment: Which controller is working and which is not working? Show the code you have in both. What configs do you have in your `$routes` ? Show something.

Comment: Many times an infinite loop can cause such an error.